# How would i increment the name of the field, when field with the same name is created?

Tags: django, reactjs, redux, django-rest-framework

I have dropdown component on my front-end. What i am trying to do is.

Every time onChange event happens i want to add selected option value as role in my backend. That works just fine for first time the option value gets selected.

What i want to do is to increment the name of the Role, if it gets selected once again. If i select Developer twice, i want the second time data to be posted as Developer 1 etc...

How could i accomplish this?

I have been googling this for an hours, and i have not already figured it out. I have tried creating validators for my serializers, checking if object exists, then if it does incrementing it for 1, and other ways.

Model

```
class Role(models.Model):   
    address1 = models.TextField(name="address1", max_length=150, null=True)
    address2 = models.TextField(name="address2", max_length=150, null=True)
    vat = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    categoryname = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    date_created = models.DateField(null=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    is_passive = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='roles', on_delete=models.CASCADE)



    def get_owner_full_name(self):

       return self.owner.get_full_name()


Serializers

from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Role

from core.serializers import DynamicFieldsModelSerializer, BasicSerializer
from user.serializers import CustomUserSimpleSerializer


class RoleSerializerBasic(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer ,BasicSerializer,):
     owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username') #
     class Meta(BasicSerializer.Meta):
        model = Role #  Model to serialize
        fields =  ('address1', 'address2','vat','categoryname','date_created', 'owner')
        depth = 0 # How deep we want to serialize fk connections



class RoleSerializerDepth(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer ,BasicSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username') #
    class Meta(BasicSerializer.Meta):

        model = Role #  Model to serialize
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 0 # How deep we want to serialize fk connections


class RoleSerializerInvestor(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer ,BasicSerializer):

    class Meta(BasicSerializer.Meta):
        model = Role #  Model to serialize
        fields =  ('address1', 'address2','vat','categoryname','date_created','owner')
        depth = 0 # How deep we want to serialize fk connections


class RoleSerializerAuditor(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer, BasicSerializer):

    class Meta(BasicSerializer.Meta):
        model = Role
        fields =  ('address1', 'address2','vat','categoryname','date_created','owner')
        depth = 0

class RoleSerializerDeveloper(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer, BasicSerializer):

    class Meta(BasicSerializer.Meta):
        model = Role
        fields =  ('address1', 'address2','vat','categoryname','date_created','owner')
        depth = 0

class RoleSerializerEducationalInstitution(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer, BasicSerializer):

    class Meta(BasicSerializer.Meta):
        model = Role
        fields =  ('address1', 'address2','vat','categoryname','date_created','owner')
        depth = 0

import json
from django.views.generic import ListView
from rest_framework import generics, permissions, status
#from django_weasyprint import WeasyTemplateResponseMixin
#Redis
from django.conf import settings
#Own
from .models import Role
from .serializers import RoleSerializerBasic, RoleSerializerDepth, RoleSerializerDeveloper, RoleSerializerAuditor, RoleSerializerInvestor, RoleSerializerEducationalInstitution
from core.permissions import HasGroupPermission, HasObjectPermission
from core.mail import send_mail
from core.views import PBListViewMixin, PBDetailsViewMixin

# Views
class RoleList(PBListViewMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    #permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, HasGroupPermission, HasObjectPermission,)
    model = Role
    table_name = "Roles" # For search and filter options (Redis key)
    required_groups= {
        'GET':['__all__'],
        'POST':['__all__'],
    }
    required_permissions={
        'GET':['__all__'],
        'POST':['__all__'],
    }
    DEFAULT_QUERY_SETTINGS={
        'pageSize':100,
        'current':1,
        'sortOrder':[],
        'sortField':[],
        'visibleFields':['id', 'address1','address2','categoryname','owner','vat','date_created'],
        'filters':{}
    }

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'GET' and self.request.user.has_perm('user.view_user'):
            return RoleSerializerDepth
        return RoleSerializerBasic

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
            """Save the post data when creating a new bucketlist."""
            serializer.save(owner=self.request.user) # Add



class RoleDetails(PBDetailsViewMixin, generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    model = Role
    table_name = "Roles" # For search and filter options (Redis key)
    required_groups= {
        'GET':['__all__'],
        'POST':['__all__'],
    }
    required_permissions={
        'GET':['__all__'],
        'POST':['__all__'],
    }
    DEFAULT_QUERY_SETTINGS={
        'pageSize':500,
        'current':1,
        'sortOrder':[],
        'sortField':[],
        'visibleFields':['id', 'address1','address2','categoryname','owner','vat','date_created'],
        'filters':{}
    }


    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'GET' and self.request.user.has_perm('user.view_user'):
            return RoleSerializerDepth
        return RoleSerializerBasic
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)




class RoleInvestor(PBDetailsViewMixin, generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    model = Role
    table_name = "Roles" # For search and filter options (Redis key)
    required_groups= {
        'GET':['__all__'],
        'POST':['__all__'],
    }
    required_permissions={
        'GET':['__all__'],
        'POST':['__all__'],
    }
    DEFAULT_QUERY_SETTINGS={
        'pageSize':100,
        'current':1,
        'sortOrder':[],
        'sortField':[],
        'visibleFields':['id', 'address1','address2','categoryname','owner','vat','date_created'],
        'filters':{}
    }
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'GET' and self.request.user.has_perm('user_view.user'):
            return RoleSerializerInvestor

        return RoleSerializerBasic


class RoleAuditor(PBDetailsViewMixin, generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):

    model = Role
    table_name = "Roles" # For search and filter options (Redis key)
    required_groups= {
        'GET':['__all__'],
        'POST':['__all__'],
    }
    required_permissions={
        'GET':['__all__'],
        'POST':['__all__'],
    }
    DEFAULT_QUERY_SETTINGS={
        'pageSize':10,
        'current':1,
        'sortOrder':[],
        'sortField':[],
        'visibleFields':['id', 'address1','address2','categoryname','owner','vat','date_created'],
        'filters':{}
    }

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'GET' and self.request.user.has_perm('user_view.user'):
            return RoleSerializerAuditor

        return RoleSerializerBasic



class RoleDeveloper(PBDetailsViewMixin, generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
   model = Role
   table_name = "Roles" # For search and filter options (Redis key)
   required_groups= {
        'GET':['__all__'],
        'POST':['__all__'],
    }
   required_permissions={
        'GET':['__all__'],
        'POST':['__all__'],
    }
   DEFAULT_QUERY_SETTINGS={
        'pageSize':10,
        'current':1,
        'sortOrder':[],
        'sortField':[],
        'visibleFields':['id', 'address1','address2','categoryname','owner','vat','date_created'],
        'filters':{}
    }

   def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'GET' and self.request.user.has_perm('user_view.user'):
            return RoleSerializerDeveloper

        return RoleSerializerBasic

class RoleEducator(PBDetailsViewMixin, generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    model = Role
    table_name = "Roles" # For search and filter options (Redis key)
    required_groups= {
        'GET':['__all__'],
        'POST':['__all__'],
    }
    required_permissions={
        'GET':['__all__'],
        'POST':['__all__'],
    }
    DEFAULT_QUERY_SETTINGS={
        'pageSize':10,
        'current':1,
        'sortOrder':[],
        'sortField':[],
        'visibleFields':['id', 'address1','address2','categoryname','owner','vat','date_created'],
        'filters':{}
    }

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'GET' and self.request.user.has_perm('user_view.user'):
            return RoleSerializerEducationalInstitution
        return RoleSerializerBasic
```

My react code

```
  onChange =  (e,i) => {
      console.log("values", e.target.value+1)
     this.props.AddRole(e.target.value);   
  }
 render(){
    const roles = [
      { label: "Investor", value:"Investor"}, 
      { label: "Auditor", value:"Auditor" },
      { label: "Developer", value:"Developer"},
      { label: "Educational Institution", value:"Educational Institution"}
    ]
      return (
          <>
         <div className="SelectOptionKlasa1">
         <Select 
         name="roleSelect"
         options={ roles}
         label="Create new role"
         onChange={this.onChange}
          />
         </div>
         </>
    )
  }
}
 export const AddRole = (categoryname, owner) => async dispatch =>{
dispatch({ type: types.ADD_ROLE});


const address = `/roles/`;
const bodyFormData = new FormData();
bodyFormData.set("categoryname", categoryname);
console.log("username ")
apiCon.post( address, bodyFormData)
.then(res => {
  dispatch(RoleAddedSuccessfuly(res.data));
     console.log("Added role", res.data);
 })
.catch(err => {
   dispatch(RoleFailToAdd("Role could not be added. "+err));
    })
  }
```

I expect every time when i post role from my frontend, if there is already role created with that name new role to be created with the same name, but plus 1. Like Developer 1, Auditor 1. I am getting categoryname: ["role with this categoryname already exists."] when i send post request.

Comment: Are you trying to do the increment because you just want to be able to save the object or do you indeed wish for the `categoryname` to be a primary key? Just making sure we don't have a case of the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) here.

Comment: Actually. I don't wish for my categoryname to be primary key. I was just trying to fix the problem with doing that. I will add new id as primary key.

Comment: To clarify, does that solve your issue or do you still have the same problem? And if you do please update your question, and also run it through a code formatter, especially that react code.

Comment: I still have the same problem.

Comment: I still see `primary_key=True` on `categoryname`?

Comment: Also don't forget to run `migrate`.